# How to create Laravel Model from Admin Panel?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to be able to create models in my Laravel application from the admin panel. It should be possible to set attributes for the table of the future model, as well as to link one model to another through the admin panel, for example Brand and Device (Samsung + laptop), for the subsequent creation of pages based on the created mapping

Do we need models for this or is it more likely to be regular tables in the database?

Comment: I'm not clear on the question? ... models are typically based on tables. If a table's columns (attributes?) are added/removed in the future, the model should still be ok. Relations are specified in the model to other related tables as well, so is there more information to know?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your question, you probably need an EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) Pattern to structure your data. Check [here](https://medium.com/@miladev95/entity-attribute-value-eav-design-pattern-in-php-c7403b949015) and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

So according to EAV specifications, `Product` is the entity, `Brand` is the attribute and `Samsung` is the value.

An example for table structure could be

Entities Table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product |

Products Table

| id | entity_id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Samsung Laptop | 2000 |
| 2 | 1 | Apple Macbook Pro | 3500 |

Attributes Table

| id | name | entiry_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | brand | 1 |
| 2 | ram | 1 |

Entity Attribute Values Table

| id | entity_id | attribute_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Samsung |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 8GB |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | Apple |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 16GB |

There are so many ways how to model EAV systems.

And for Laravel there was a good package created for it
https://github.com/rinvex/laravel-attributes
But currently the repo is obsolete and not maintained.

You can model EAV yourself with Laravel Eloquent ORMs

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The thing is that Samsung and Notebook should be different models and a link should be created between them through another table. But these two models should be initially created in an automated way, so that the user can create them from the admin panel. These are kind of directories, on which new pages will be built.